# Is there any way to read articles without subscription?

Tags: reference-request, education, publishing

This is not mathematician question but I think it's related. How I can get access to some of "[Software: Practice and Experience](http://ordering.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/subs.asp?ref=1097-024X&doi=10.1002/%28ISSN%291097-024X)" articles without subscription?

Any advice is welcome. Sorry if I'm posting at wrong site. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know this too... how can you read math journals?

Comment: You might be able to just go to a university/college that has access, and use their internet (either on your laptop, or a terminal in a library or lab). You certainly can at my university (University of Minnesota-Twin Cities). In fact, since it is a land grant university, we must make available all of our resources to anyone interested.

Comment: I really don't know which tags would be appropriate to this question :-( I'd say [tag:reference-request] is the closest I can find.

Comment: Now you can use Sci-Hub.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically a few possibilities come to mind immediately:

- Preprint could be found at http://arxiv.org/ (thanks to Hans for reminding me this possibility).
- The author could have the preprint of the paper on his website. (google for it)
- Many mathematical journals allow to download for free any paper that is older than some period (usually about 5-10 years).
- You can also find copies of older papers at specialized sites (try to google for projecteuclid, numdam, "gottingen digital library"; but there is a lot more). Based on my experience so far I'd say that if the journal has a Wikipedia article and some volumes are freely available, you'll find a link in the Wikipedia article. (Examples: Wikipedia article for [Mathematische Annalen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematische_Annalen) has a link to [GDZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDZ). Wikipedia article for [Duke Mathematical Journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_Mathematical_Journal) has a link to projecteuclid. Wikipedia Article for [Acta Arithmetica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acta_Arithmetica) links to matwbn.)
- If you have a friend at some university/institution that might have a subscription, try to ask him.

Comment: ...or it could be on a preprint site, such as arxiv.org.

Comment: Well, problem is that you can google very limited number of articles and as you said, they can be in pre-print condition (i.e. with mistakes).
S:P&E didn't open even really out-dated articles from 1970-s.

Anyway thanks and hope this will help somebody.

Comment: @PoorGuy I do have access to that yournal (or at least some issues). I can download a few articles and send you per email. Check my website (in my profile) to get my email address. (BTW we do not have something like private messaging at this site, do we? Or have I just overlooked it?)

Comment: If all else fails one also can try to contact authors directly.

Answer (score 11):

This is addressed at both PoorGuy and quanta's questions. Researchers don't generally subscribe to journals on an individual basis; we rely on institutional subscriptions at our universities. Many journals don't even have an option for an individual subscription, they only have prices for institutional use.

If you live near a large university you may be able to go to the university library and read articles there. The print collections of most libraries are open for public browsing, and online access subscriptions usually work from any on-campus computer. Many libraries have a "friend of the library" program that will let anyone get a library card for a nominal annual fee. This may include computer access and the ability to check out books.

If you go to a smaller university, you can often use their document delivery services to get a copy of a paper that you don't have access to. These are sometimes called "interlibrary loan" but for a journal paper they are much more likely to just send a copy of the paper than to ship a printed journal.  If you are a library member (even at a public library), you should always look into this option before buying a paper directly from the publisher.

If you are at a university you also are likely to have access to MathSciNet, which is a very helpful resource for finding math papers.

Comment: In the comments to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30127/is-there-an-intuitionist-i-e-constructive-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-primes/30133#30133) there are some questions about intuitionism that perhaps you might be able to shed some light one. I'll delete this comment once I know you've seen it.

Comment: Thanx. Clever advice, but sadly i don't have such opportunity. Universities in my city doesn't have access to such networks. City isn't small, population is 1M, but our libraries very outdated in my field (not math, but computer science).

I'm depend on subscriptions to such journals since my field is rapidly developing. Only way is online access to more advanced libraries with subscription to my journal.