# Question on Malcev's _Immersion of an Algebraic ring into a skew field_.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

I'm reading the paper [*Immersion of an algebraic ring into a skew field*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/) by Malcev. Doi: [10.1007/BF01571659](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01571659),
[GDZ](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0113&DMDID=DMDLOG_0047).

On the third page of the paper, he writes that

> If $\alpha\beta\sim\gamma\delta$ and the words $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ have the same length then
>   $$
> \alpha=\mu m,\quad \beta=n\nu,\quad \gamma\sim\mu m',\quad\delta\sim n'\nu,\quad mn\sim m'n'
> $$
>   where $m,n,m',n'$ are each one of the letters $a,b,c,d,x,y,u,v$.

How is this property easily seen? Malcev starts be starting with the semigroup of all words generated by eight letters $a,b,c,d,x,y,u,v$, where the operation is concatenation. He defines the pairs of two-letter words as "corresponding" $(ax,by)$, $(cx,dy)$ and $(au,bv)$ and says two words $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by changing $ax$ to $by$, $cx$ to $dy$, etc. or vice versa.

He also proves that there are never any overlap ambiguities of what two letters could be replaced, but I don't see why the above quoted property follows so easily. Thank you.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I've copied the links from the [other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165194/why-is-the-absence-of-zero-divisors-not-sufficient-for-a-field-of-fractions-to-e), I guess it is the same paper.

Answer (score 0):

Malcev states before that in a word $ \dotsc m n p \dotsc$ we cannot replace $mn$ *and* $np$ by another word. This means that the relations don't overlap. Regardless how you change a word by the relations, the classes of the letters $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\{x,y,u,v\}$ stay the same at each position. So if we want to change $\alpha \beta$ into $\gamma \delta$, we have to change $\alpha$ into $\gamma$ and $\beta$ into $\delta$ separatedly (this is the case that the letters $m,m',n,n'$ don't appear; probably one should add this), or at one step we come across the two words and make something like $(\mu m)(n \nu) \sim (\mu m')(n' \nu)$. Of course this is not really formal. It can be made precise using induction on the length of the deduction.