# Constructive proofs and omega-consistency

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

That old MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/definition-of-non-constructive-proof) discusses the notion of “constructive proof”, and the answers explain
that there  is no one definition of what "constructive" or "non-constructive" means.

Recently, I thought of the following definition : let us say a theory $T$
(at least as strong as Peano arithmetic, say) is “constructive” if whenever
a nonconstructive proof about integers exists, then there is a constructive
equivalent, i.e. whenever $T$ proves (“non-constructively”) that $\exists \ \text{integer  } n,\  \phi(n)$ for some predicate $\phi$, then there is an integer $n_0$ such that $T$ proves $\phi(n_0)$.

There is a connection between this notion and $\omega$-consistency : if $T$ is consistent
but $\omega$-inconsistent, then T is not “constructive”.
But (unless I missed something), if we only know $T$ is $\omega$-consistent, we cannot know in advance if $T$ will be constructive or not.

Is it known whether PA,ZF or ZFC are “constructive” in this sense ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PA is  not constructive in this sense. For note

> $PA \vdash \exists x(\varphi(x) \lor \forall y\neg\varphi(y))$.

Now take the case where $\varphi(x)$ is $T(e,e,x)$, which expresses the relation which holds when $x$ codes the steps in a halting computation by Turing machine  number $e$ run on input $e$. This   Kleene relation is decidable, and indeed is  expressible in the language of $PA$. If, for given $e$, there were always a number $n$ such that

> $PA \vdash (T(e, e, n) \lor \forall y\neg T(e, e, y))$,

then we could do a terminating search for $n$ given $e$ by enumerating $PA$ proofs, and by then deciding whether $T(e,e,n)$ it would be decided whether Turing machine $e$ halts on input $e$, assuming $PA$ is sound.  But we know the halting problem is undecidable.

Comment: I don't know who should get credit for that cute proof. And I don't know either if there is some other nice proof which takes a rather different  route to bringing out this fundamental difference between Heyting Arithmetic and Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: There are also ways to do this that do not require the halting problem. For example, for every sentence  $\phi$, just classical logic and $(\exists n)[n \not = 0]$ proves $(\exists n)[(n = 0 \land \phi) \lor (n \not = 0 \land \lnot \phi)]$. However, proving that a particular value works for $n$ requires either proving $\phi$ or proving $\lnot \phi$.

Comment: @CarlMummert  Thank you Carl, I prefer your version.

Comment: And so do I :-)

Answer (score 1):

This property is called the "numerical existence property". It is common in constructive systems and rare in systems with classical logic. There is an [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties) that lists several references.