# Interpretation of $\sigma$-algebra and filtrations (follow-up question)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

This is a follow-up question to [Interpretation of sigma algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23776/interpretation-of-sigma-algebra), particularly to [Jun Deng's excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26800/48999). He used the example of two coin tosses to explain some fundamentals of how filtrations and conditional expected values work.

The following three $\sigma$-fields (for times $0,1,2$) have been presented:

$\mathcal{F}_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.

$\mathcal{F}_1=\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{HH,HT\},\{TH,TT\}\}\supset \mathcal{F}_0 $

$\mathcal{F}_2=\{\emptyset, \Omega,\{HH,HT\},\{TH,TT\},\{HH\},\{HT\},\{TH\},\{TT\}\}\supset \mathcal{F}_1$

Now, his intuitive explanations makes perfect sense. What I am after though, is a **more rigorous mathematical derivation** of these. I understand that these are the pre-images of the random variable, but I can't wrap my mind around it.

Lastly, I have a similar problem with the following:

$$E[X|\mathcal{F_2}](\omega)=X(\omega)\qquad\text{for every}\ \omega $$
Intuitively, this makes sense, mathematically, I am at loss.

Comment: As mentioned over there, unfortunately, $\mathcal F_2$ is **not** a sigma-field.

Comment: [Maxim](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273287/intuition-behind-measurable-random-variables-and-sigma-algebra/) made the mistake about $\mathscr{F}_2$ too.

Comment: @BCLC Do not modify significantly the math content of a question, especially after some aspects of it were addressed in comments.

Comment: @BCLC Please do not make significant changes to the mathematical content of a question. Only the OP can know whether such changes meet their intention. (Besides, the changes didn't make $\mathcal{F}_2$ a $\sigma$-algebra either.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Okayyyyyy. Why is that not a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @BCLC If an algebra (we're in a finite situation, so algebra and $\sigma$-algebra coincide) contains every singleton of a finite set, then it's the full power set. The edited version didn't contain $\{HH,TH\}$ for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer Was $\mathscr F_2$ supposed to be $2^{\Omega}$?

Comment: @BCLC Jun Deng might know. But since that's the only algebra on $\Omega$ containing all of $\{HH\},\{HT\},\{TH\},\{TT\}$, that's not unlikely.

Comment: @DanielFischer But if not? I don't see how that is not a sigma-algebra. Why does it need to contain every Singleton? So is it correct to say that F1 and F0 are not sigma-algebras as well

Comment: @BCLC $\mathcal{F}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}_1$ are $\sigma$-algebras. As the family $\mathcal{F}_2$ is defined, it contains all singletons. An algebra of sets containing all singletons contains all finite subsets (since every finite subset is a finite union of singletons), and when the whole space is finite, it thus contains all subsets.

Answer (score 0):

'I understand that these are the pre-images of the random variable'

They COULD be. I mean given any sigma-algebra, you could just make a random variable that had that sigma-algebra for its set of preimages right?

There's no rigour there, I think. When you flip a coin and see the result, there are more things we know almost certainly.

Previously the only events whose probabilities were 0 or 1 were the ones in $\mathscr{F_0}$. After the first flip, we have added 2 events. Depending on the toss, we would know which of those events has probability 1 and which has probability 0.

---

As for the last one, what you got there on the LHS is a conditional expectation.

**Conditional expectation with respect to an event A is defined constructively(*)**:

Given $X$ on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$

$E(X|A) = \frac{1}{P(A)}\int_A X dP$, provided of course $P(A) > 0$ (Would you use conditional probability on an event with probability zero?).

**Conditional expectation with respect to a sigma-algebra $\mathscr{G}$ is not defined constructively(*)** (which I guess means no explicit formula or something):

It is some random variable $Z$ s.t.

$\sigma(Z) \subseteq \mathscr{G}$

and

$\int_G Z dP = \int_G X dP \ \forall G \in \mathscr{G}$.

We usually denote $Z \doteq E[X|\mathscr{G}]$.

So, the rigorous explanation is that:

1. $Z = X$ is $\mathscr{F}_2$-measurable (check that $\sigma(X) \ \subseteq \ \mathscr{F}_2$).
2. Check that:

$\int_G Z dP = \int_G X dP \ \forall G \in \mathscr{F}_2$ where $Z \doteq E(X|\mathscr{F}_2)$ in this case = $X$.

So just plug in Z = X to get:

$\int_G X dP = \int_G X dP$.

This clearly holds $\forall G \in \mathscr{F}_2$ or any $\mathscr{G}$.

Conditional expectation may not seem intuitive since its definition is not constructive (*). Try proving its [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties). What I did above was prove 'Stability'.

P.S. I think [non-constructive (*) definitions need existence and uniqueness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence_theorem#.27Pure.27_existence_results) or something.

Existence of conditional expectation is due to something called the Radon-Nikodym derivative or theorem, which looks like, iirc afaik, the rigorous version of differentiating one probability distribution to another.

Uniqueness involves continuity of measure.

---

(*)

1. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Discussion):

'A couple of points worth noting about the definition:

This is not a constructive definition; we are merely given the required property that a conditional expectation must satisfy.'

[This](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=2Qr3BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=conditional%20expectation%20constructive&source=bl&ots=otUST7Bt7i&sig=mCWuuRH9Kcgyuz64q1uayhTmAdU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBGoVChMIh9a2t9WqxwIVgxeUCh1cZwMU#v=onepage&q=conditional%20expectation%20constructive&f=false) seems to give a constructive definition.

[This](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=bHKBWbxTmwcC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=%22Elementary%20Stochastic%20Calculus%20with%20Finance%20in%20View%22%20%22constructive%22%20%221.33%22&source=bl&ots=kp7pVUWZYx&sig=Gqlszd0W6fSq5Tw67mHf9S3G2IQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIyOLwh9iqxwIVgUaUCh3a6w8q#v=onepage&q=%22Elementary%20Stochastic%20Calculus%20with%20Finance%20in%20View%22%20%22constructive%22%20%221.33%22&f=false) doesn't seem to do so.

Also: [Definition of "non-constructive proof"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/definition-of-non-constructive-proof)

2. Apparently, as Did pointed out, [construction is possible if the sigma-algebra in question is finite](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=EW6FDA1UmNUC&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=conditional%20expectation%20constructive&source=bl&ots=EEffhvXvgb&sig=m2qa4X4FueoWKrsJQ7nma0mgK78&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAmoVChMIh9a2t9WqxwIVgxeUCh1cZwMU#v=onepage&q=conditional%20expectation%20constructive&f=false). I think that is what is being pointed out [here](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=EW6FDA1UmNUC&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=conditional%20expectation%20constructive&source=bl&ots=EEffhvXvgb&sig=m2qa4X4FueoWKrsJQ7nma0mgK78&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAmoVChMIh9a2t9WqxwIVgxeUCh1cZwMU#v=onepage&q=conditional%20expectation%20constructive&f=false).

Comment: Thank you for answering an older question, it's always a bit frustrating to get no answers. Since posting this question, my understanding of probability has (luckily) expanded, so this all makes much more sense now. And yeah, the non-constructiveness of the conditional expectations keeps bugging me again and again, looking forward to the day when I'll be able to say that I "got it".

Comment: @DahnJahn I think the Radon-Nikodym derivative is supposed to explain it. Haven't read on it yet