# Query about a proof in "Numbers & Proofs" by Allenby

Tags: divisibility, integers

Part of a proof that there are infinitely many primes. (I have no special interest in the thing being proved).
Page 105 of the 2003 digital printing, proof of Statement 14: (This is part of a proof by contradiction.)

---

"Consequently *q* divides both N and N-1 and, hence their difference N - (N-1), i.e. *q* | 1. However this is impossible since *q* is prime."

---

In my self-study, this sounds both *ugly* and *redundant*. For me, *q* cannot divide 1 if *q* > 1.
***q* being prime is irrelevant.**

Nothing divides both N and N-1 other than 1. For example, 2 could divide N and N - 2; 3 could divide N and N - 3. (Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic)

Why might he have said such a thing? Is it just 1 is not prime, so q is not 1?

Comment: The assumption that $q$ is prime was probably needed at an earlier part of the proof. At the stage of the proof you're referring to, all that's needed is $q > 1$, which is true since $q$ is prime.

Comment: Yes, the writer meant "Since $q$ is prime, $q>1$ and so $q$ can not divide $1$."

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21338/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217034/242) for more conceptual insight on this and closely proofs.

Comment: Thanks quasi and lulu. It makes more sense now. Thanks Bill for compiling the links.