# Number Theory : Infinitude Of Primes - a different proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

I was doing some basic Number Theory problems and came across this problem :

> - Show that the integer :  $Q_{n} = n ! + 1$, where $n$ is a positive integer, has a prime divisor greater than $n$.
> - Conclude that there are infinitely many primes.

***My Solution (partial)***

> - We know that as $Q_{n}$ is $\gt$ $1$ $\Rightarrow$ $Q_{n}$ has a prime divisor $p$
> - Let us assume , that $p$ $\le$ $n$
> - If $p \le n$ then $ p \mid n! $
> - So , in the equality ; $Q_{n} - n ! =  1$ , $p$ divides the LHS $\Rightarrow$ it also divides $1$
> - But that is not possible as no prime divides $1$
> - Hence , we have achieved a contradiction and there exists a prime divisor $>n$

***My Question :***

I am not able to prove the infinitude of primes from this result , how can I do that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proof implies that given any prime $\,\color{#c00}p\,$ there exists a larger prime (dividing $\,Q_{\large\color{#c00}p}$), therefore the set of primes is infinite.

**Remark** $\ $ Because this way of proof is *not* by contradiction, it yields constructive information: iterating the above yields an algorithm to generate an infinite sequence of primes, viz.

$$\begin{align} 
&Q_1 = 1!+1 = 2\quad\ \text{has prime factor}\ \ \ \, 2 > 1\\
&Q_2 = 2!+1 = 3\quad\ \text{has prime factor}\ \ \ \, 3  > 2\\
&Q_3 = 3!+1 = 7\quad\ \text{has prime factor}\ \ \ \, 7 > 3\\
&Q_7 = 7!+1 = 71^2\ \text{has prime factor}\ \ 71 > 7\\
&\quad\ \ \ \vdots\qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad\ \ \vdots
\end{align}\qquad $$
This proof is a minor variation on [Euclid's classical proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) (which also [was not by contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242), despite many inaccurate historical claims to the contrary).

Answer (score 5):

HINT: If there were only finitely many primes, there would be a largest prime; call it $q$. Now consider what you know about $Q_q$.

Comment: Hi , @BrianMScott - I am not able to follow , exactly , would be grateful if you can expand upon your answer :)

Comment: @Michael: It’s correct, therefore it’s not flawed. Whether it’s needlessly complicated is a matter of opinion and taste; since I saw it before I saw the one that I suspect that you have in mind, I can’t really agree that it’s all that complicated.

Comment: @pranav: You’ve proved that $Q_q$ must have a prime divisor larger than $q$, but by hypothesis $q$ is the largest prime ...

Comment: But , @BrianMScott , in $Q_{n}$ -- n is not given to be prime -- why do you say that *"by hypothesis $q$ is the largest prime"* ?

Comment: @pranav: Read my answer again. I assumed, in order to get a contradiction, that there were only finitely many primes. In that case there must be a largest prime, **which I’m calling** $q$. In other words, the hypothesis for the remainder of the argument is that $q$ is the largest prime.

Comment: Thanks @BrianMScott , I got it :)

Comment: @pranav: Whew! :-) You’re welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Let $P_n$ be a prime dividing $Q_n$. You've proved that $P_n>n$. The following is an infinite sequence of distinct primes:
$$\left\{2,P_2,P_{P_2},P_{P_{P_2}},P_{P_{P_{P_2}}},P_{P_{P_{P_{P_{2}}}}},\ldots\right\}.$$
Therefore, there are infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose that there were finitely many primes. Let $n$ be the largest prime. Obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not beat around the bush. For any given prime $p$ you can certainly find a positive integer $n$ such that $p$ *is not greater* than$~n$. So there cannot be a largest prime.