# Prove that any number consisting of $2^n$ identical digits has at least $n$ distinct prime factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that any number consisting of $2^n$ identical digits has at least $n$ distinct prime factors.

This is a quite well known problem. But I cant find a way to start. Any hint will be helpful.
**Note**: This is a problem from the book **104 Number Theory** written by Titu Andrescu. There is an answer but that is not clear to me.

Comment: So this question comes down to factoring $a_n := 111 \cdots 1$, with $2^n$ $1$'s? Since all the other such numbers are equal to $ka_n$ for $k=1, 2, \ldots, 9$?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein This comment solved my problem .. Should I delete this post?

Comment: It's not a completely trivial question. I'd probably just go ahead and accept Robert Israel's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $(10^{2^n}-1)/9$ is divisible by $10^{2^k}+1$ for $k = 0, \ldots, n-1$, and these are relatively prime.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ Let $\,a_{N} = 10^{\large 2^N}\!\!-1.\,$ $\,a_{N+1}\! = (10^{\large 2^N})^{\large 2}-1 = (10^{\large 2^N}\!\!+1)(10^{\large 2^N}\!\!-1) =  (a_{N}\!+2) a_N $ has as at least one more prime factor than $\,a_N,\,$ because $\,1 < a_{N}\!+2\,$ is *coprime* to odd $a_{N}.$

**Remark** $\ $ This can be viewed as an analog of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes when [recast in the form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242) that $\,(N+1)N\,$ has more prime factors than $N$.

Answer (score 1):

We have declared that our number, $N$, is composed of $2^n$ identical digits,

let's call that digit $d_{0,p}$ ( let's suppose $N$ is in it's base $p$ representation.)

Therefore it must have the form:

$$N=\sum _{j=0}^{{2}^{n}-1}d_{{0,p}}\cdot{p}^{j}$$

and we know that:

$$d_{0,p} \in {\{1,2,3,...,p-1,p}\}$$

And therefore this restricts the p-adic representation of $N$ to the set:

$$ N \in  \left\{ {\frac {{p}^{{2}^{n}}-1}{p-1}},2\,{\frac {{p}^{{2}^{n}}-1}{p-1}},3\,{\frac {{p}^{{
2}^{n}}-1}{p-1}},...,{\frac {p \left( {p}^{{2}^{n}}
-1 \right) }{p-1}} \right\} $$
Working on the assumption that the minimum element of such a set will have the minimum number of distinct prime factors ($\omega(N)$) of any possible $N$ for that base $p$, we find that this minimum element will always have a number of distinct prime factors equal to $n$:

$$\omega(\frac {{p}^{{2}^{n}}-1}{p-1})=n$$