# Infinite prime proof using factorial plus one or product of primes plus one?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

My instructor provided a proof for the Theorem: The number of primes is infinite.
Proof by Contradiction
Assume finite number of primes this means there is a largest prime say $p$.
Now lets say there is a prime $q$ in which $q | p!+1$. However this means $q > p$, since
we have found $q$ to be greater than the assumed largest prime there is a contradiction
thus there is an infinite number of primes.
From the above proof does $p!$ is p factorial or should it mean p! is the product of 
primes ergo $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ ergo is $p!$ assumed to be the product of primes? 
I assume it is the product of primes because most of the proofs
 I have seen would say
$p = p_1\times p_2\times...\times p_n$ where $p_1, p_2,...p_n$ are all primes.

Comment: $p!$ is indeed $p$ factorial.

Comment: Well, $p!+1$ is the product of number from $1$ to $p$.

Comment: Products $(\prod)$ or factorials aren't needed: [More simply:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242) $n(n+1)$ has more prime factors than $n$, so there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $\times$ using `\cdots`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either one.  The product of all the primes up to $p$ is called the primorial and sometimes written $p\#$.  We have $p\#$ divides $p!$ because $p!$ includes all the primes less than $p$ as factors along with other numbers.  The statement that any prime dividing $p\#+1$ or $p!+1$ must be greater than $p$ goes through and provides a prime greater than $p$ as required.

Comment: "because p! includes all the primes less than p as factors along with other numbers." Doesn't p! include all the primes up to p including p?

Comment: Yes it does @DanielTellier, but is not a matter of significance. the answer is fairly well written. +1 for primorial and making it clear that the question isn't actually relevant whether it is product of primes upto p or product of natural number upto p :-(

Answer (score 2):

The usual proof works with the product of the  primes up to $p$, but this argument with the factorial $p!$ works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

The factorial and the primorial are different things. Given a positive integer $n$, the factorial $n!$ is divisible by each integer from $1$ to $n$, whether it's prime or not. e.g., $5! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 = 120.$

What is $5$ primorial? There is some disagreement: it could be $2 \times 3 \times 5 = 30$, or it could be $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 = 2310$ (the product of the first five primes).

But if we are agreed on the definitions, we can use either factorials or primorials. The important thing is that we have some number divisible by lots of distinct primes, and one which is divisible by none of those (add or subtract $1$ from the former to obtain the latter).

The factorials have a slight disadvantage in that they get larger quicker. Compare $29! = 8841761993739701954543616000000$ to the product of the primes from $2$ to $29$, which is $6469693230$.

Now notice that $6469693231 = 331 \times 571 \times 34231$, while the least prime factor of $8841761993739701954543616000001$ is $14557$.

Comment: The size of the product cannot be a disadvantage in such a proof since it plays no role. But it would come into play if one interpreted the proof *constructively* to obtain an algorithm generating an infinite sequence of primes.

Comment: @BillDubuque I feel like the factorials have a disadvantage both from a pedagogical perspective and from the perspective of elegance. A handheld scientific calculator can go farther with the primorials than with the factorials before switching to scientific notation. And from the standpoint of elegance, the factorials have a lot of repeated prime factors, while the primorials have only distinct prime factors.

Comment: But the proof does not involve calculations with *specific* numbers.

Comment: It sure doesn't, which is why it's most often stated without reference to either factorials or primorials. If you have to choose one or the other, choose primorials. With the factorials you might confuse people like young Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Proof that primes are infinite using factorial. $1 +$ the factorial of a number is a number that is not divisible by the numbers that make up the factorial with the exception of $1$. At this point two cases are possible: $n! +1$ is prime or $n! +1$ is the product of primes that are not part of $n!$ of which the smallest is at least $n + 1$. Reasons why prime numbers are infinite.