# A problem on number theory involving concepts of primes, divisibility and factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, integers

Prove that for any positive integers $m$ and $n$, there exists set on $n$ consecutive positive integers each of which is divisible by a number of the form $a^m$ where $a$ is any integer.

To be honest, I'm not even sure what the question is asking. I mean should I write $a=1$ and move on, or is there an actual non trivial solution.

Any hint/ help is appreciated!

Comment: By the exact wording of the problem statement, letting $a=1$ for all $n$ terms is a valid solution. However, I suggest you contemplate the probably intended question where each term is supposed to be a multiple of a proper $m$th power $>1$.

Comment: @Aditya_math This problem is from which book ?

Comment: @SunainaPati CTPCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Chinese Remainder Theorem problem.  Take the system

$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{2^m}$$

$$x+1 \equiv 0\pmod{3^m}$$

etc.

$$x+n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p_k^m}$$

where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime.

Comment: So is it essentially asking for a proof of CRT?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the moduli have to occur in the numerical order as you present them. Is it not possible to construct $k!$ such solutions by taking the $p_k^m$ in each possible order? For $k=3$ e.g., can't we take $2^m$ second or third rather than first (using $3^m$ or $5^m$ as the first modulus)?

Comment: @KeithBackman Nobody said that you have to take the moduli in numerical order.  The guy asked for a hint, I gave him a hint.  It's a homework problem posted with no effort shown, so a hint is all he gets.

Comment: @B. Goddard Right. I just wanted to be certain I wasn't missing something subtle with regard to the specifics of your hint.

Comment: @B.Goddard i just read your comment and appreciate your answer but just wanted to let you know this wasn't a homework problem, as a matter of fact my school doesn't even teach number theory. This was a problem in a book i am solving. In this chapter, CRT had not been introduced yet so i was not sure what to do which is what i mentioned in the OP.

Comment: The point is that it's a "textbook" problem.  If CRT hasn't been introduced yet, then the purpose of the problem is to lead you to the CRT.

Comment: It suffices for the moduli to be powers of (pairwise) **co**primes, which can be generated by the method used in [Euclid's proof of infinitely many primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242)