# Prove that Fibonacci sequence contains An infinite Sub-sequence That all its element are co-prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Prove that Fibonacci sequence contains An infinite Sub-sequence That all its element are co-prime.

Prove Two Sub-sequence different

> Instruction: Fermat numbers.

$----------------------------$

**attempt 1:**
$F_n$ is strong divisibility sequence , $\gcd(F_m,F_n)$=$F_{\gcd(m,n)}$
we need to prove there an infinite sequence of coprime integers.

Comment: Foreign? Do you mean co-prime?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah i did edit my post, Sorry about that.

Comment: How do you justify that all the even indexed Fibonacci numbers are coprime?

Comment: @RossMillikan I cant prove that, so I already edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: by the simple proof in [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) the Fibonacci sequence $\,F_n\,$ is [*strong* divisibility sequence,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence) i.e. $\,\gcd(F_m,F_n) = F_{\gcd(m,n)},\,$ so the problem reduces to proving that there is an infinite sequence of coprime integers (indices), for which there are many obvious methods (some that don't require *primes*, e.g. [Euclid's famous constructive algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242) that recursively generates an infinite sequence of (co)prime integers).

Comment: Dubque Thanks for the Hint, i read all the link's u sent. i have already prove that gcd(Fm,Fn)=Fgcd(m,n) but i don't get it how i can prove that have an infinite sequence of coprime integers

Comment: @atb The final link above shows how Euclid's method constructs an infinite sequence of pairwise coprime integers (or primes). Use any such sequences as indices for $F$ to map it to pairwise coprime fib's.

Comment: Thanks, understood but how its indices for F to map it to pairwise coprime fib's i don't get it . sorry.

Comment: @atb If $\,i\neq j\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{\gcd(n_i,n_j)=1}\,$ then $\,\gcd(F_{n_i},F_{n_j}) = F_{\color{#c00}{\gcd(n_1,n_j)}}\! = F_{\color{#c00}{1} }=1\ \ $

Comment: I understand what u write but how its can be  An infinite Sub-sequence That all its element are co-prime in Fibonacci, you said its simple proof but I don't see it so easy, you maybe can rescue me and give a full proof I will apricate that . I read everything said in your post

Comment: @atb  It's not clear what you don't understand. Please be more precise.

Comment: I understand what you wrote about fibonacci series being a strong divisibility sequence. But  Im struggling to grasp how to implement this into showing a concrete proof. I cant find any sub series in the Fibonacci numbers that all elements are co prime. I have a few guesses but they all lead me to dead end  e.g. $F_{5n+1} , F_{5n-1}$ or not understanding how to prove it. If u could please show me explicitly one example I would be grateful. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @atb As a concrete example let's choose our induces to be $\,n_k := p_k = k$'th prime, which are clearly pairwise coprime. Then by above these prime indexed fib's $\,F_2,F_3,F_5,F_7,\ldots $ are also pairwise coprime.

Comment: Thanks I understand that much better. although not all prime indices are prime numbers, for example $F_{19}=4181=37\cdot113$. so how do we know for a fact that the kth prime index will be co prime with any other prime index? In other words how do I know that this stands for all  prime indices?

Comment: @ATB As emphasized above, the indices need only be pairwise $\rm\color{#c00}{co}prime$. viz. $\,\color{#c00}{\gcd(p,q)=\bf 1}\Rightarrow\gcd(F_p,F_q) = F_{\color{#c00}{\gcd(p,q)}} = F_{\large\bf{\color{#c00}1}} = 1.\ $ Clearly unequal primes are coprime. $\ \ $