# Any finite integral domain is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm going through the Rings section of Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, and I have a question about an early Corollary's proof.

Proof: Let R be a finite integral domain and let a be a nonzero element of R. By the cancellation law the map x->ax is an injective function. Since R is finite this map is also surjective...

How does R being finite make the map surjective?

Comment: Note that on the right side of this page under Related you will find that the question has been answered on MSE several times.

Comment: @AndréNicolas maybe the list changes slightly, but I do not actually see any related questions addressing the main question. The title question has of course been answered several times, but in all cases I'm aware of, the solution to the question here was taken as granted. So we have a surprise case where the real related question is not well-detected by the software :)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only so many elements, and it is injective (one-to-one) and the domain and range have the same cardinality. Hence it must be surjective. There is not 'space' for it to be otherwise.

Comment: Right, it's coming back. This is similar to injectivity and surjectivity being equivalent for linear transformations among vector spaces of equal dimension.

Comment: @Doop Something like that, yes :)