# The relation between prime ideal and simple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I saw "Any simple ring is a prime ring" as an example in Prime ring@wiki.

Can anyone show me how to proof it?

Also, on the other side, is any prime ring a simple ring?

Thanks.

Comment: For the second question, not all prime rings are simple. Consider any integral domain which is not a field, e.g. the integers.

Comment: What if it is finite?

Comment: All finite integral domains are fields. See here for more: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/why-is-a-finite-integral-domain-always-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unital ring $R$ is called simple iff $R$ is not zero ring and the only ideals of $R$ are $R$ and $0$; prime iff $R$ is not zero ring and for any nonzero ideals $I,J$ of $R$, $IJ\neq 0$. Since the only nonzero ideal of a simpile ring $R$ is $R$ itself, and $R^2=R\neq 0$, it's clear that simple rings are prime rings.

If $R$ is commutative, simple rings = fields, prime rings= integral domains. Not every integral domain is a field, the simplest example is $\mathbb Z$ I think.

Comment: That is, "Any simple ring is a prime ring" is a wrong statement?

Comment: @user131605 It's a right statement if you only consider rings with identity. It is the converse statement that is wrong.