# Cardinality of a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Why can we be sure that if $A$ is a Unique Factorization Domain and has at least one irreducible element, then $A$ is infinite?

I can't see how to prove this. Does it have any connection with primes?

Many thanks!

Comment: It would pretty much have to have something to do with primes, since being a UFD is about primes.

Comment: Any domain with a nonzero nonunit is infinite, since finite domains are fields. More generally, If all but finitely many elements of a ring $\rm\:R\:$ are units or zero-divisors (incuding $0$), then all elements of $\rm\:R\:$ are units or zero-divisors, [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/62571/242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Consider all powers of that irreducible element.

Comment: And how can I be sure that, for some $n$, the $n$-th power of that irreducible isn't already in the UFD?

Comment: @dlc UFDs are in particular rings.

Comment: Oh, I see. If that happened, then that irreducible would have to be a unit and that's a contradiction, right? I mean, is it true that $a^n$ unit implies $a$ unit?

Comment: @dlc Of course it is.

Comment: Forget it! It's clear now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dlc For more details maybe you want to look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/62551/121097).