# Finite integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, integral-domain, finite-rings

I encountered a problem:

> Every finite integral domain is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{ Z }_{p} $.

I know that finite integral domain is isomorphic to a field, but I have no idea on how to construct a homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ (or maybe it is wrong, but I haven come up with a counterexample).

Comment: take $\mathbb{Z_{3}}[i]$ for instance it is a finite integral domain with 9 elements but I don't see it being isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{p}}$ for any prime p, assuming p is a prime.

Comment: @shrey Oh, yes, you are right. Here p may not be a prime, but your example $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[i]$ still works since it is not a cyclic group.

Comment: This is not true. There are finite fields of each order $p^n$. These are certainly finite integral domains but they are not  isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$ if $n>1$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @shery and @lhf, the conterexamples come from their comments.

A finite integral domain which actually is a (finite) field will have the order of the form ${p}^{n}$, where $p$ is a prime. Then when $n>1$, it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{{p}^{n}}$ since $\mathbb{Z}_{{p}^{n}}$ is not a field.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest counter example would be the integral domain
$$R = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$$ under matrix multiplication and addition.