# Let $p$ be a prime then which of the following are true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be a prime. Pick each correct statement from below. Upto isomorphism,

1. there are exactly two abelian groups of order $p^2$.
2. there are exactly two groups of order $p^2$.
3. there are exactly two commutative rings of order $p^2$.
4. there are exactly one integral domain of order $p^2$.

**My try:**
The number of abelian groups up to isomorphism, of order $p^2$ is equal to the partition of $2$. So 1 is correct. Again any group of order $p^2$ is abelian, hence 2 is also correct. But I am confused with 3 and 4. In case of 4, we know that there is a unique field of order $p^2$, and a field is an integral domain. But will this imply 4? Any hints/ answer will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: For 4., a finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: Oh yes, missed that. thanks @Watson. What about 3?

Comment: You may want to try your hand on proving that there are *exactly three* commutative rings with identity having $p^2$ elements (up to isomorphism).

Comment: hmmm any hints @egreg? I definitely want to prove.

Comment: A finite commutative ring is artinian, so it is a product of local rings. Either there is a unique factor or two; in the latter case we get $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$; in the former case, either the ring is a field (and is the unique Galois field of order $p^2$) or it has a nontrivial maximal ideal (and is $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $4.$, a [finite integral domain is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548).

For $3.$, think about $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb F_{p^2}$.

Comment: got it. Thanks.