# GF(2) is a field, binary field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to prove that $GF(2)$ with the XOR and AND operations is a field, but I do not know how to prove this creating an isomorphism and not proving all the properties for be a field.

Is it correct think this, building an isomorphism to $Z_2$ ?, How can I prove this statement more easily?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: If you know that $\Bbb Z_2$ is a field, then yes: you should build an isomorphism between $GF(2)$ and $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: $Z_2$ is the set of classes formed by {[0],[1]} and $GF(2)$ is the set formed by {0,1}, then I can construct a function f that sends [0] to 0 and [1] to 1, then clearly f is bijective, is it correct?

Comment: that's exactly the right idea.

Comment: Are there another way to prove that $GF(2)$ is a field?

Comment: You could also apply exactly whatever logic was necessary to prove that $\Bbb Z_2$ was a field.

Comment: Is it possible to construct a ring and then a maximal ideal that forms all GF(2)? then GF(2) is a field

Comment: That seems excessive.  If you know that $GF(2)$ is a ring, it suffices to show that it is commutative and that the non-zero element has a "multiplicative inverse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to "create an isomorphism". You verify that $GF(2)$ is a finite ring (this is almost obvious), which has no zero divisors. Then you can use a well-known fact - for a proof see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/why-is-a-finite-integral-domain-always-field?rq=1), that every such finite integral domain is a field. Or you verify the field axioms directly, of course.