# Showing an integral domain is a field using a function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that every finite integral domain R is a field.

I am given the following hint: For an element $r\neq 0 $ decide if the function $f : R \to R $ defined by $f(s)=rs $ is injective and/or surjective.

My question is about the hint.

Firstly i am assuming they mean that $ r, s \in R $ ?

If $f$ is an injective function that would seem to imply that $f$ is simply a permutation all the elements in $R$? if $f$ is injective or surjective then it is a bijection.

lastly what does this map have to do with anything? shouldn't it be $f:R \to F $ where $F$ is a field with that many elements then show that $f$ is a homomorphism and a bijection so $R$ (our integral domain) would be isomorphic to $F$ which is the field?

Comment: This hint is used in almost every solution to duplicates of this question on the site, so I think you will find ample explanation. Please search first

Comment: No offence i read the linked "exact duplicate" and i dont understand a word of the linked post, ill spend some more time with it and see if i can figure out how its related but i want to make it clear that your's and my definition of  "exact" are very very different things.

Comment: well of course questions do it have to be *verbatim* duplicates. That would be silly. The point is that one of the solutions shows you exactly how your hint works, and it’s not hard to see your problem is a simple corollary. Do you check all the solutions to the linked questions? I’m pretty sure there are duplicates of your question even you would admit to there.  I picked this one because of the quality answer and votes.

Comment: I should probably have linked this one;, so nobody would argue: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62548/29335

Comment: i think the problem is that what you see as obviously the same is something i am looking at and going, hey look a bunch of symbols i don't know what they are. i found a post that answers why the hint works but i still dont actually understand why we are choosing that map and why we land back in R not F or whether or not f is a homomorphism. I want to be clear i am not contesting that you believe the answer is obviously in those other posts merely that i don't have the mathematical background to understand them in the given context. Anyway ill ask my prof instead.

Comment: Dear Faust: Yes, I do regret not finding the second link first. The second link, in fact, explains both problems (and your hint) well. That is my mistake. If you can manage to put your unhappiness about this aside for a moment, and look at the links and their duplicated questions, you'll find many upon many explanations that show how your hint works. If you read them, you would find your question answered. Regards

Comment: And I probably should spell out why the first link applies: There is always a map $\mathbb Z\to R$ defined by $f(1)=1$. The image of this map is called the [prime ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ring) of $R$. This is, of course, isomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb Z$. Since $R$ is finite here, the quotient must be of the form $\mathbb Z/(p)$ for a prime $p$. And that is a field. Since $R$ is finite, it must be finite dimensional over the field $\mathbb Z/(p)$.

Comment: That is all well and good but the real point is that the hint given in both places works the same way: if you have a finite domain $R$ and nonzero $a\in R$, then $r\mapsto ar$ is an injective homomorphism on a finite set, hence it is surjective. So, there exists $r$ such that $ar=1$. So, $a$ is a unit. You even seem to understand that all up to this point, so it is strange you don't see the conclusion. This answers your question "what does this have to do with anything": the answer is: "it immediately and directly shows you every nonzero element has an inverse."

Comment: I've reopened it because I agree it's not the best duplicate. It should still be closed as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/why-is-a-finite-integral-domain-always-field, however. Anyone reading the solution to this question, and/or its duplicates, would find all of the questions in this post completely and clearly addressed.

Comment: Ironically you actually answered the remainder of my questions in your comments above that i couldnt figure out from the articles linked below and if anything i think that the first linked post has a more elegant implement of the hint. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63950/proof-that-an-integral-domain-that-is-a-finite-dimensional-f-vector-space-is-i 
and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/why-is-a-finite-integral-domain-always-field

Comment: You can call it irony if you like: from my perspective you are just shortchanging yourself on what you would have been able to accomplish by reading it yourself if you had persevered. What I just said was there the whole time.  I didn't want to spell it out for you, but I saw no other way to convince you. In the future, please don't make me spoil it again! Regards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68459/discussion-between-faust-and-rschwieb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need to clarify just what is a given in this question; I normally take an "integral domain" to be a  unital commutative ring $R$ with no zero divisors; that is, $R$ is possessed of a multiplicative identity $e$ such that $ea = ae = a$ for $a \in R$; and if $a, b \in R$, then $[ab = 0] \Longrightarrow [a = 0 \vee b = 0]$; as far as I am aware, this definition is currently widely accepted; but the ubiquity of variants in use cannot be denied.  For example, apparently a notion of "integral domain" which doesn't require the existence of $e$ but does demand that $[ab = 0] \Longrightarrow [a = 0 \vee b = 0]$ is still widely accepted.  Therefore an attractive feature of the following argument, based as it is upon functions $f_r:R \to R$, $f_r(s) = rs$, is that it allows us to establish both the existence of a multiplicative identity *and* of multiplicative inverses concurrently.  So we may as well drop any assmuption that $R$ need have a unit.

It works like this:

If $f_r:R \to R$ is given by

$f_r(s) = rs, \tag 1$

with $r \ne 0$, then $f_r$ is manifestly injective, since

$f_r(s_1) = f_r(s_2) \Longleftrightarrow rs_1 = rs_2 \Longleftrightarrow r(s_1 - s_2) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow s_1 - s_2 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow s_1 = s_2, \tag 2$

where we have used the fact that $R$ is an integral domain to infer that

$r(s_1 - s_2) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow s_1 - s_2 = 0 \tag 3$

in (2); since $R$ is finite and $f_r$ is injective, $f_r$ is also surjective and thus there exists $e \in R$ with

$re = f_r(e) = r; \tag 4$

$e$ is in fact unique in accord with (2).  That $f_r$ is surjective further implies that, for any $s \in R$, there is some $t \in R$ with

$tr = rt = f_r(t) = s; \tag 5$

then

$se = (tr)e = t(re) = tr = s, \tag 6$

which shows that the element $e$ is in fact a multiplicative unit for all of $R$; thus $R$ is unital, and we may once again invoke he surjectivity of $f_r$ to affirm the existence of some $r' \in R$ with

$rr' = f_r(r') = e; \tag 7$

thus $r' = r^{-1}$ is a multiplicative inverse of $r$.

We can obviously define a similar function $f_s$ for any non-zero $s \in R$; the identity element $e_s$ so obtained will in fact be $e$ since in the usual manner we may write

$e_s = e_s e = e; \tag 8$

furthermore, $s \ne 0$ implies $f_s$ is surjective, as above, and thus we establish the existence of $s^{-1}$:

$ss^{-1} = s^{-1} = e. \tag 9$

We have now established that $R$ has a multiplicative identity element $e$ and a multiplicative inverse $r'$ for every element $r \in R$; thus $R$ meets all the requirements to attain the status of field.

As far as our OP Faust's closing questions are concerned:

1.)  Yes, $r, s \in R$.

2.)  Yes, $f_r$ being injective/surjective is, since $R$ is finite, exactly equivalent to $f_r$ being a permutaion of the elements of $R$.  That each such $f_r$ is a permutaion of $R$ is the key idea behind this proof.

3.)  The map $f_r$ is really a just convenient way of keeping track of the multiplicative action of $r$ on $R$; a notational/conceptual covenience, if you will.  The essential thing is that multpilication by any nonzero element of $R$ generates a permutation of this finite set.  We can't simply take $f$ to be a homomorphism to a field since, at the beginning of the argument at least, we haven't yet shown a field is involved.  Until we've shown otherwise, we don't even know if there *is* a field with the same number of elements as $R$.