# Cardinality of Primes in UFDs over Infinite Sets

Tags: number-theory, infinity, unique-factorization-domains

As we know, there are infinitely-many Integer primes per, e.g
, Euclid's proof.

Is it also true that there are infinitely-many primes in every UFD defined over an infinite set? I tried to see if Euclid's proof extended to UFDs, but I was not able to make it work. Thanks in Adance.

Comment: No. Take any infinite field. Then you have no prime elements. If you count prime elements up to association, you could take $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ($p$-adic integers) . This is a UFD, but there is a unique prime element up to association.

Comment: @GreginGre: Thanks. Could this happen in a ring which is not a field?

Answer (score 2):

As GreginGre points out, the answer is no, since every field is a UFD that does not contain *any* prime elements. However, fields are indeed the only UFDs in which this can occur. To see this, let $R$ be any UFD that is not a field; then $R$ is [automatically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/why-is-a-finite-integral-domain-always-field) infinite, and $R$ contains at least one prime element $p$. We will show that $R$ has infinitely many prime elements. If the group of units $R^\times$ is infinite, then we are done, since the family $\{\lambda p:\lambda\in R^\times\}$ is a collection of distinct prime elements of $R$. Thus assume that $R^\times$ is finite; since $R$ is infinite, we are now in a position to replicate the proof of Euclid's theorem. Indeed, suppose $p_1,\dots,p_n\in R$ is any finite collection of prime elements of $R$. Since $R$ is infinite, the set $\{1+p_1\dots p_n s:s\in R\}$ is infinite as well, and since $R^\times$ is finite there thus exists some $s\in R$ such that $1+p_1\dots p_ns$ is not a unit. Since $R$ is a UFD, there is then some prime element $q$ that divides $1+p_1\dots p_ns$, and we cannot have $q=p_i$ for any $i\leqslant n$, so $q$ is a prime element of $R$ not among $p_1,\dots,p_n$. In particular, $R$ has infinitely many prime elements, as desired. So, to answer your question, any UFD that is not a field has infinitely many prime elements.

---

On the other hand, again as GreginGre comments, if you are willing to consider examples that have finitely many prime elements *modulo units*, then there *can* be counterexamples that are not fields. Here is a recipe for constructing such examples. Let $R$ be any UFD that is not a field and let $p_1,\dots,p_n\in R$ be any prime elements of $R$. Then the subset $S=R\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n\langle p_i\rangle$ is a complement of prime ideals, hence multiplicatively closed, and by [Kaplansky's criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140584/about-the-localization-of-a-ufd) the localization $S^{-1}R$ is a UFD. But every prime element of $S^{-1}R$ is associate to one of the $p_i/1$ (why?), so $S^{-1}R$ has only finitely many primes up to associativity, as desired.

For a very tractable example of this construction, let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, so that $p_1,\dots,p_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are just integer primes. Then the ring $S^{-1}R$ indicated above is just the subring $$\left\{\frac{a}{b}:p_i\nmid b\text{ for each }i\leqslant n\right\}$$ of $\mathbb{Q}$; as an exercise, try to check directly that this ring is a UFD and that all of its prime elements are associate to some $p_i$.