# Try for:Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity. Then, if $I$ is prime ideal, then it is maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity. Then, if $I$ is prime ideal, then it is also maximal ideal.

I know its solution, but I want discuss the following try:

Notation:

$1$)$U(R)$ is the set of units of $R$.

$2$)$ZD(R)$ is the set of zero divisors of $R$.

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity, then $R=U(R)\cup ZD(R)$.

$I \neq R$ since $I$ is prime ideal.

Now,assume $I \subseteq J \subseteq R$ (J is ideal of $R$):

$1$)If $U(R) \cap J \neq \emptyset $, then $J=R$ ,so $I$ is maximal ideal.

$2$)If $U(R) \cap J=\emptyset$, then $J \subseteq ZD(R) \subset R$, so here we need to prove $J=I$.

Let $x \in J$, then $\exists y \in R$ such that $xy=0_{R} \in I$.

Since $I$ is prime ideal ,we have $x \in I$ or $y \in I$.

$x \in I$ leads to $I=J$.

But how can I prove $I=J$ from $y \in I$.

Comment: Why not just this argument: If $I$ is prime, then $R/I$ is a finite integral domain, hence a field. Thus $I$ is maximal. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/why-is-a-finite-integral-domain-always-field).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you, but I know this solution,  my question is just discussing another idea, and this is allowed in this site standards.

Comment: **Please don't** post *other* proofs (most all of which would be dupes). This question concerns the OP's specific method.

Answer (score 1):

> $R=U(R)\oplus ZD(R)$

It'd be better to write $R=U(R)\cup ZD(R)$ as neither of the things being added are necessarily closed under addition.

You can't prove it from these facts alone

1. $I$ prime
2. $I\subseteq J\subseteq ZD(R)$

because there are counterexamples. For example, for a field $k$, let
$$R=k[x,y]/(xy,x^2) \\
I=(X) \\
J=(X,Y)$$
where $X$, $Y$ denote the respective images of $x$ and $y$ in the quotient $R$.  $I$ and $J$ are both prime, and $XJ=\{0\}$.

You have to actually use something more (in your case, you are given that $R$ is finite.)

> But how can I prove $=$
> from $∈$

You mean $y\in I$, right?

Comment: Can you, please, clarify the example you put?

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar Clarify what?