# Relation between Nilpotent Matrix and identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

A non-zero matrix $A$ is said to be nilpotent for some positive integer $k\geq2$. If $A$ is nilpotent then is $I+A$ invertible?? Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: This is probably a tenplicate. As a hint think about the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A+I$, by that specific order.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325318/prove-that-if-matrix-a-is-nilpotent-then-ia-is-invertible

Comment: You might also want to read the first sentence again. As currently written, it does not really make sense.

Comment: @GitGud It looks like if we got each of five voters to report a single different duplicate, we would have gotten all of them listed in the closure template...

Comment: @rschwieb Gotta improve the synergy.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer:

> If $A^k=0$, consider the product $$A^{2n+1}+I=(A+I)(A^{2n}-A^{2n-1}+\cdots+I)$$ For a sufficiently large integer $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $\,A^k=0\;$ , then:

$$(A-I)(A^{k-1}+A^{k-2}+...+A+I)=A^K-1\ldots$$

...but you have $\,A\color{red}+I\;$ , so what to do...? :)