# Prove that $S-1$ is an isomorphism if $S:V\to V$ is a linear map and $S^n = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Not exactly sure how to approach this: my idea was to try to show that $S-1$ is injective and since $S-1$ is a linear map from V to V, it follows that $S-1$ also surjective by the rank-nullity theorem (on the condition that V was finite-dimensional), and hence $S-1$ is bijective.  I am still stuck.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots$.

Comment: do you know the geometric series formula? that and the assumption that there exist $n$ such that $S^n=0$ are very useful. you'll find that you can explicitly write what the inverse is as a polynomial in $S$.

Comment: Dupe of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents
and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325318/prove-that-if-matrix-a-is-nilpotent-then-ia-is-invertible  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483173/relation-between-nilpotent-matrix-and-identity-matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An eigenvalue argument is not required.

Given that

$S^n = 0, \tag 1$

we observe that

$(I - S) \left ( \displaystyle \sum_0^{n - 1} S^k \right ) = (I - S)(I + S + S^2 + \ldots + S^{n - 1} ) = I - S^n = I, \tag 2$

which shows that $I - S$ is invertible and that

$(I - S)^{-1} = \displaystyle \sum_0^{n - 1} S^k. \tag 3$

Note that this result binds no matter what the dimension of $V$ might be; in particular, $\dim V$ need not be finite.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

For a scalar $\;\alpha\; ,\;\; S-\alpha I\; $ is an isomorphism iff $\;\alpha\;$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $\;S\;$ . But it is given $\;S\;$ is nilpotent, thus its only eigenvalue is...