# How to prove the equality of determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a square matrix, and B a nilpotent. (size of A and B is same)

Assume AB=BA

Show that, det(A+B)=det(A)

Comment: The matrices have coefficients in an arbitrary field?

Comment: Yes! Real or Complex!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since they commute, they are simultaneously upper triangularizable.  For some unitary $U$, we can write
$$
UAU^* = \pmatrix{\lambda_1&&&&*\\&\lambda_2\\&&\ddots\\&&&&\lambda_n}: = T_A\\
UBU^* = \pmatrix{0&&&&*\\&0\\&&\ddots\\&&&&0} := T_B
$$
Note that $\det(A + B) = \det(T_A + T_B)$

Comment: Better replace "unitary" by "invertible" and $U^T$ by $U^{-1}$ if the matrices have coefficients in an arbitrary field, wlog algebraically closed.

Comment: thank you!! your solution is simple and wonderful!!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg does [Schur-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Generalized_Schur_decomposition) work in arbitrary fields?  I'm not so sure this solution method extends.  In fact, I'm not even sure the statement is true in fields of finite characteristic.

Comment: Well as I've indicated, don't think about such complicated things special to $\mathbb{C}$. It is a general fact about algebraically closed fields that (as you say) commuting matrices are simultaneously upper triangulizable. The latter means that $U A U^{-1}$ is triangular for some invertible matrix $U$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah, so simultaneous upper-triangularization does extend, even if the concept of a "unitary matrix" is no longer in play.  The only complicated thing that's added with Schur is that over $\Bbb C$, we can choose our similarity (to an upper-triangular matrix) to be unitary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof which avoids triangularization. The proof works over any field $k$.

**Case 1:**  $\det(A)=0$.

Then $\det(A+B)=0$, since otherwise $A+B$ is invertible, and then $A=(A+B)-B$ is invertible too ([SE/119904](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents)), namely via the geometric series. This is a contradiction.

**Case 2:** $\det(A) \neq 0$.

Then $A$ is invertible. Then $C:=A^{-1} B$ is nilpotent with $\det(A+B)=\det(A) \det(1+C)$, so that it suffices to prove $\det(1+C)=1$. But this is clear since $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $C$ and therefore $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $1+C$. (In general, eigenvalues add when we add constants.)