# Verification of proof that if $R$ is a commutative ring, $a$ is a unit and $b^2=0$ then $a+b$ is also a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Here's what I have so far and I would like to know if I am right or if my proof needs to be edited:

Since $a$ is a unit it means $a1=a$, with $1$ being the unity element

We know $b^2=0$ and this means $b=0$

So $a+b=a+0=a=a1$ hence $a+b$ is a unit.

Comment: The question is a duplicate of this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/119904/29335 but I guess this is a solution verification, hence distinct.

Answer (score 6):

The element $a$ is unit means that there's $a'$ such that $aa'=1$. Now we have

$$(a+b)(a'-(a')^2b))=aa'-a(a')^2b+ba'+(a')^2b^2=1$$
so $a+b$ is unit.

Comment: How did you come up with the (a'-$(a')^2$b) part?

Comment: By analogy with the real analysis we have
$$\frac1{a+b}=\frac{a^{-1}}{1+a^{-1}b}=a^{-1}(1-a^{-1}b+(a^{-1}b)^2+\cdots)$$
and recall that in this ring we have $b^2$ so we have only two terms in the previous sum.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof does not make any sense. How do you conclude $a+b = a+0$, for instance? $b^{2} = 0$ does not imply $b = 0$; consider, for instance $2 \in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Also, your definition of a unit is not correct. A unit is an element of a ring with a multiplicative inverse. If $a$ is a unit, then there exists $u \in R$ such that $au = 1$. $a\cdot 1 = a$ is true for every element of $R$ by the definition of the multiplicative identity in a ring!

However, the proposition given is actually a special case of a more general fact: if $R$ is a commutative ring and $a$ is a unit and $b$ is nilpotent, then $a+b$ is a unit.

Here is my hint in your case:

Consider $(a+b)(a-b) = a^{2}-b^{2} = a^{2}$. Since $a$ is a unit, can you use this to construct an inverse to $(a+b)$?