# Proof that in the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of an invertible matrix, the diagonalisable matrix is invertible

Tags: matrix-decomposition

Let $F$ be a field and $n\in \mathbb N^*$.

The (additive) Jordan-Chevalley decomposition theorem states that for any matrix $M\in \mathcal M_n(F)$ whose characteristic polynomial splits into linear factors there exists a unique decomposition $M=D+N$ where $D$ is diagonalisable and $N$ is nilpotent and commutes with $D$.

[This proof](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wuyifan/ExpositoryArticles/LinearAlgebraicGroups/Jordan_Decomposition_in_Algebraic_Groups.pdf) of the multiplicative Jordan-Chevalley decomposition theorem uses the additional (given, I think) fact that if $M$ is invertible, then $D$ (from the additive decomposition) is also invertible, but I can't see why.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents.

Comment: I'm under the impression the statement I'm trying to prove is the converse, am I wrong ? He assumes $u$ (i.e. my $D$) to be a unit, I myself am trying to prove that while knowing that $D+N$ (or $u+a$ in the post you mention) is a unit.

Comment: $N$ is nilpotent, then so is $-N$. Thus $D=(D+N)+(-N)$ is a unit.

Comment: PS : I think I remember reading somewhere that $D$ even has the same eigenvalues as $M$ but I'm not sure ? Can you confirm this ? If so I'll post later on for a proof if needed.

Comment: The argument is identical: $D-\lambda I$ is not a unit if and only if $D-\lambda I +N$ is not a unit.