# General solution of equation $AX + X + A = 0$ where A is nilpotent matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

We need to find the general solution for the following equation:
$$AX + X + A = 0$$
Here is the very beginning of my solution: 
$$AX + X = -A$$
but $A$ is nilpotent matrix, so $-A$ is also nilpotent, then $(AX + X)$ is nilpotent too, so
$$\det(AX + X) = 0$$
what should i do next to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

"Re-phrase" your expression, into

$$\mathbf{AX + X + A = 0 \Leftrightarrow (A+1)X = -A}$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the identity matrix, such that $\mathbf{1 \cdot X = X}$. Now, it suffices to show that a solution exists if and only if $\mathbf{A+1}$ is invertible, thus :

$$\mathbf{X = -A(A+1)^{-1}}$$

The solution will also be unique.

**Nerdy edit :**  An interesting fact about inversibility is the correlation with the geometric series. Specifically, if you can show that $\mathbf{(A+1)^{-1}}$ is invertible and $\|A\| < 1$, then

$$\mathbf{\frac{1}{A+1}} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^n\mathbf{A}^n$$

which is the exact and unique solution to the problem.

Comment: it's easy to proof, that it's invertible, thank you, but why can we say that $AX + X = (A + 1)X$ and not $X(A + 1)$ ?

Comment: @envygrunt It really depends on how your matrices are defined, but generally no, the row of the multiplication operation regarding matrices is important.

Comment: but in our problem it doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Saying that $\mathbf{A\cdot B = B \cdot A}$ when talking about matrices isn't always true. For your given problem, it is : $$\mathbf{AX + X = A \cdot X + 1 \cdot X = (A+1)X}$$ Now, if more information can be yielded and you can show that the row of multiplication doesn't matter for your matrices, then it could be the other way as well, yes.

Comment: thank you again, now it's clear

Answer (score 1):

Factor the right hand side:

$$
(A+I)X = -A
$$

and then to find $X$ you can use the fact that [the identity plus nilpotent is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents).