# Prove I-T is invertible, if $T^n = 0$ for some positive integer, T some linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I’m stuck solving this problem.  Given $T^n=0$, I know that the column vectors of T will be linearly dependent. However, it’s unclear that subtracting a linearly dependent matrix from the identity gives another linearly independent (invertible) matrix. How do I begin to show this?

The problem continues: show that 
$(I-T)^{-1} =I+T+...+T^{n-1}$
and guess how one would give the formula. Perhaps that leap of intuition will occur once I understand the first half better, but a hint here would be appreciated as well.

Comment: It seems so. Should I delete the question then?

Comment: $T^n= 0$ implies $\sigma(T)= \{0\}$ so $\sigma(I-T)= 1-\sigma(T)= \{1\}$. This doesn't contain $0$ so $I-T$ is invertible.

Comment: @mechanodroid I’m unfamiliar with the sigma you’re referring to. Where can I read about it?

Comment: @ThorKamphefner $\sigma(T)$ is the [spectrum of the matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix) $T$, i.e. the set of all eigenvalues of $T$. A matrix is invertible if and only if $0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Comment: @ThorKamphefner:  You can find an answer here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents

Comment: If $I-T$ were singular (not invertible) then $1$ would be an eigenvalue of $T$, but since $1$ is not a root of the polynomial $X^n$ that by assumption annihilates $T$, this cannot be the case. Or restated without referring to eigenvalues: if $I-T$ were singular there is a nonzero vector $v$ in its kernel, which therefore satisfies $T(v)=v$. But then $v=T(v)=T^2(v)=\cdots=T^n(v)=0$ contradicts that $v$ was nonzero.