# Vector space of finite dimension, and a subalgebra of $L(V)$ whose all its elements are nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension, and let $A$ be a subalgebra of $L(V)$ where all its elements are nilpotent. Show that $\bigcap_{f\in A} \ker(f)$ is not reduced to $\{0\}$.

$L(V)$ means linear maps in $V$.

Comment: Is this over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, or an arbitrary field?

Comment: @RobertIsrael This should be true over any field.  It seems to be either a lemma to or a result of Engel's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel's_theorem).

Comment: @Batominovski if we assume Engel's theorem, the result is fairly immediate.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I haven't thought about using Engel's Theorem, although it looks like a tool that trivializes this problem.  Maybe, there are other elementary solutions.

Comment: @Batominovski the "[useful lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel's_theorem)" from the wiki page is ostensibly a dual version of what we're trying to prove.

Comment: In other words: it's equivalent to prove that if $A$ is such an algebra of nilpotent elements, then there is a proper subspace $V_1 \subsetneq V$ for which each $f \in A$ satisfies $f(V) \subset V_1$

Comment: Actually, [propostion 9.7](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Max.Neunhoeffer/Teaching/liealg/liealgchap4.pdf) here answers exactly this question

Comment: I just realized that the only proof of Engel's Theorem I know uses this exact problem, and the only proof of this problem I know is as @Omnomnomnom found above.  Maybe, somebody here will find a different proof.

Comment: @Seginus do let us know when you've had a chance to check the linked proof. Let us know if you've seen any of the tools used there before.

Comment: What contest is this from, please?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom we didn't study modules and Lie algebra so I think there's an easier solution

Comment: @Gerry MyersonThis is a contest given in our school last year

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133689/an-algebra-of-nilpotent-linear-transformations-is-triangularizable for a slightly stronger claim.

Answer (score 0):

First, we prove the claim in a simple setting, which which allows us to understand the general proof.

Let $V$ and $A$ be as in the problem.

---

### Simple case:

Suppose that $A$ is generated (as an algebra) by the nilpotent elements $a,b \in L(V)$. Suppose furthermore that all $a^{2} = 0$, $b^{2} = 0$, $(ab)^{2} = 0$, and $(ba)^{2} = 0$. Then, $A$ is the linear span of the elements
\begin{align}
a, b, ab, aba,\text{ and } bab.
\end{align}
These elements suffice, since by assumption we have $abab = baba = 0$. First of all, note that
\begin{equation}
\cap_{f \in A} \ker(f) = \ker(a) \cap \ker(b).
\end{equation}
The idea is now to construct a non-zero vector $v \in \ker(a) \cap \ker(b)$.

Now, since $a$ is nilpotent, it is clear that there is a non-zero element $x \in V$ with $ax \neq 0$. Furthermore, we have that $ax \in \ker(a)$.

Now, if $bax = 0$, then $ax \in \ker(a) \cap \ker(b)$. If $bax \neq 0$, then $bax$ is a non-zero element in $\ker(b)$.

Now, if $abax= 0$, then $bax \in \ker(a) \cap \ker(b)$. If $abax \neq 0$, then $abax$ is a non-zero element in $\ker(a)$.

Our procedure terminates, because $baba = 0$, hence $babax = 0$, hence $abax \in \ker(b)$.

We conclude that
\begin{equation}
 \cap_{f\in A} \ker(f) = \ker(a) \cap \ker(b),
\end{equation}
contains at least one non-zero element.

---

### General case:

Let us now consider the more general case. As a vector space $A$ is the linear span of a finite number of elements $a_{1},\dots, a_{k} \in A$.
By assumption, there exist numbers $n_{1},\dots,n_{k} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $a_{i}^{n_{i}} = 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

We will need the following lemma, for which I do not have a proof yet.

> There exists a number $N < \infty$, such that the following holds.
>   Let $\sigma:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{1, \dots, n\}$ be arbitrary, then the element
>   \begin{equation}
>  a_{\sigma(N)} a_{\sigma(N-1)} \dots a_{\sigma(2)} a_{\sigma(1)} = 0.
> \end{equation}

Now we can prove the claim in a way very similar to the proof above.

Let us write $X = \cap_{f\in A} \ker(f) \subseteq V$.

Let $x \in V$ be arbitrary. Either $x \in X$, or there exists an element $a_{i}$ such that $a_{i}x \neq 0$. In the first case we are done, so suppose that $a_{i}x \neq 0$. Define $\sigma(1) = i$. Let $0 \neq y \in V$ be of the form $a_{\sigma(l)} \dots a_{\sigma(1)} x$. Then either $y \in X$, or there exists an element $a_{j}$ such that $a_{j}y \neq 0$. Define $\sigma(l+1) = j$. In this way, we inductively define $\sigma: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{ 1, \dots n \}$.

The lemma tells us that $a_{\sigma(N)} \dots a_{\sigma(1)}x = 0$, hence, this inductive process stops.

Comment: I don't see why $abab=0$. What definition of nilpotent are you using?

Comment: Ah, you are right of course, there should be some $n$ such that $(ab)^{n} = 0$, for some reason I set $n=2$. I feel that I should still be able to fix the proof, but this will make it significantly more difficult.