# Wanting to show $a+x$ is a unit for unit $a$ and nilpotent $x$

Tags: commutative-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Units and Nilpotents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents)

If $a$ is a unit and $x$ is nilpotent, I'm trying to show that $a+x$ is a unit.

**Pf.:** If $a$ is a unit, there exists a non-zero invertible element $a^{-1}$ s.t. $a\cdot a^{-1} = 1$, and if $x$ is nilpotent then $x^n$ for some finite $n > 0$ is equal to zero.

So if $a+x$ is a unit, there exists a non-zero invertible element $(a+x)^{-1} = 1/(a+x)$ and dividing through by $a$, I get: $(1/a)/(1+x/a)$ but I am having some trouble expanding this power series it looks like.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents).

Comment: This is good except that it does not generalize for other than the case if u = 1

Comment: Yes, it does: look at the comments following Arturo’s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $a + x$ as $a( 1+ xa^{-1})$ since $a$ is a unit. Notice that $(xa^{-1})$ is nilpotent. By the result in the link above we have that $1 + xa^{-1}$ is a unit. Now the product of two units is a unit so you are done.

You can see the following link too: [Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1 then why does $a\in N(R) \Rightarrow 1+a\in U(R)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68191/let-r-be-a-commutative-ring-with-1-then-why-does-a-in-nr-rightarrow-1a-in/68201#68201)

Answer (score 12):

Let's be "naive": what about $$\frac{1}{a+x}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{a}}=a^{-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{a}+\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^3}{a^3}+...\right)$$ Well, now we just need to observe that the above series is...a finite one (can you see why?), and all the denominators are well defined as $\,a\,$ is a unit, so...