# $1-r$ unit in ring with $r^n = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with $r \in R$ and $r^n = 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $1-r$ is a unit in $R$.

I tried to use the geometric sum but I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: That technique works.  Note that it is a finite sum by your assumption.

Comment: I dont know how to apply this correctly to the task

Comment: See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68191/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $(1-r)(1+r+\ldots+r^{n-1}) = 1$ if $r^n=0$.

Comment: This is one of the most duplicated questions on the site. Please next time duplicate it as such instead of answering Thanks.