# Primes and irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why is it true that if a unique factorization domain has an irreducible then it has infinitely many irreducibles? I am guessing that it has something to do with them being primes?

Comment: Euclid's proof of the infinitude of the primes works in any UFD.

Comment: @Fredrik It is *not* true that Euclid's proof generalizes to any UFD since there are UFDs with only finitely many primes, e.g. the subring of $\mathbb Q$ obtained by adjoining inverses of all but finitely many primes. Euclid's proof breaks down because $\rm\:1 + p_1 p_2\:\cdots\:p_n\:$ might be a unit, so need not yield a new prime. But one can avoid this problem in a ring with fewer units than elements, see my [proof here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/742)

Comment: @Jakucha Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The assertion is not quite true as it stands, nor are the comments quite correct. That is, the Euclid-style argument easily fails: for example, the ring R obtained from the integers by allowing arbitrary odd denominators (=localization of $\mathbb Z$ at 2) is a PID (the only ideals are generated by powers of 2), and is a UFD, therefore, but has only one irreducible/prime element (modulo units), namely, 2.

How does Euclid's argument fail here? For example, 2n+1 is a *unit* in this ring, so has no non-unit divisors. It is "big", but a unit, nevertheless.

Edit: and/or perhaps I misunderstood the intent, namely, as commented, the multiples 2/odd are distinct, although associate. Bill Dubuque's discussion of rings with fewer elements (see above link) may address the question's intent?

Comment: Right; but it has infinitely many irreducible elements, since $2/m$ is irreducible for every odd $m$...

Comment: @Paul Yes, Euclid's argument may fail if there are too many units. However, it does generalize as follows: An infinite ring R has infinitely many max ideals if it has fewer units than elements, see my [proof here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/242)

Answer (score 10):

Note that if $x$ is irreducible, then so is $ux$ for any unit $u$.

Let $D$ be a UFD, and let $x$ be an irreducible in $D$.

If a domain is finite, then it is a field, so the fact that $D$ contains an irreducible means that $D$ is infinite.

1. If $D$ has infinitely many units, then the elements $ux$ with $u$ a unit form an infinite set of pairwise distinct irreducibles. (Note that since $x$ is irreducible, it is nonzero, so $ux=vx$ implies $u=v$).
2. If $D$ has only finitely many units, then we *can* proceed along the lines of Euclid's proof: let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be any finite list of irreducibles. Then the collection of all elements of the form $1+(x_1\cdots x_n)k$ with $k$ in $D$ is infinite. They can't all be units (since there are only finitely many units), so at least one is a nonunit, hence divisible by some irreducible. But it cannot be divisible by any of the $x_i$ (same argument as Euclid's), so there must be some irreducible not on our original list.

I'm pretty sure I've seen Bill Dubuque give the proof above... ah, yes, as he's [mentioned before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/742), if the cardinality of the set of units is smaller than the cardinality of the ring, then the argument above goes through.

Note that, in a sense, case 1 is a bit of a cheat, since even though we found "infinitely many irreducibles", we did not guarantee infinitely many pairwise **non-associated** irreducibles. But as Paul Garrett's example shows, we cannot hope to achieve that in general; in fact, for every finite $n\gt 0$ there are UFDs that have exactly $n$ associate classes of irreducibles: e.g., localize $\mathbb{Z}$ away from $n$ primes.