# Is the Jacobson radical of a ring with finite spectrum and nilpotent nilradical nilpotent?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I tried to solve 1.3.3 in Bosch, *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*.

I did not find a way to solve it. But I found this: [Finitely many prime ideals ⇒ cartesian product of local rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834213/finitely-many-prime-ideals-rightarrow-cartesian-product-of-local-rings).

And I am not able to show that in a commutative ring with unit, $R$, which has only finitely many prime ideals and nilpotent nilradical the Jacobson radical is also nilpotent.

I would be happy if someone could give me a hint how to solve it. Thanks. You can find the exercise from Bosch in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.  For instance, consider the localization $R=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, or more generally the localization of any domain at a height $1$ prime.  The only primes in $R$ are $0$ and $(p)$, the nilradical is $0$, but the Jacobson radical is $(p)$.

Comment: Thank you! So I am not too stupid to solve the exercise, but too stupid to read the other post.