# Polynomial with no roots over the field $ \mathbb{F}_p $.

Tags: polynomials, roots, finite-fields

How can I show that for any prime $p$ and any $d\ge 2$ there exists a polynomial of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ with no roots? ($\mathbb{F}_p$ is the finite field with $p$ elements).
Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: Take $1+\prod(x-a)$, where the product runs over all the elements of the field. https://yutsumura.com/prove-that-any-algebraic-closed-field-is-infinite/#:~:text=f(x)%3D1%2B,)%E2%88%88F%5Bx%5D.&text=Hence%20the%20finite%20field%20F,closed%20field%20must%20be%20infinite. Edit: I've just realised that the polynomial must be of a prescribed degree. Still, I think the comment provides some help.

Comment: I need it for every possible degree $d\ge 2$. So for example if $p=7$ and $d=3$, how I can show it?

Comment: The proof via mimicking Euclid's argument (cf. 1st comment) has been discussed here many times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/858429/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even more than that, there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$. The field $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is a field extension of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{F_p}$. The multiplicative group a finite field is cyclic, so let $\alpha$ be a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}^{\times}$, and then we have $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}=\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$. Since $[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p]=d$ it follows that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $d$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.

Comment: How do you construct $\mathbb F_{p^d}$?

Comment: @WimC The existence of $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is a known theorem. Take the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{p^d}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: I'm sure WimC knows about the existence of all the finite fields. I interpreted the comment to ask for a proof *without* resorting to the existence of splitting fields etc. [That can be done](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125854/11619), but it is a bit hairy. I take the splitting field route any day of the week :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The question about construction of $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ was to check if the reasoning wasn’t circular (i.e. if it used an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$). I also just noticed that the question you linked to is basically about the counting arguments in my second answer. I think it adds some value, so I’ll leave it here. The counting approach is simple enough to derive from first principles.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(x)=x^d-x$ has at least two roots in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, namely $0$ and $1$. Thus, viewed as a map $f\colon\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, it is not injective, hence also not surjective. Pick $a\in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ that is not in the image. Then $g(x):=x^d-x-a$ has no root in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

You can even find an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$.

The field $F_{p^d}$ has characteristic $p$, hence it can be viewed as an extension of $F_p$ with degree $d$.

By the primitive element theorem, there exists some $\alpha \in F_{p^d}$ such that $F_{p^d}=F_p(\alpha)$. Call $M$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Then $M$ is irreducible, the ring $F_p[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to $F_p[X]/(M)$, which is a field, hence $$F_p[X]/(M) \simeq F_p[\alpha]=F_p(\alpha)=F_{p^d}.$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

As a result, the polynomial $M$ is irreducible with degree $d$.

Remarks : there exists a formula providing the number of  irreducible with degree $d$ on $F_p$.

Comment: How do you construct $F_{p^d}$?

Comment: $F_{p^d}$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{p^d}-X$. View https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field

Answer (score 1):

For any $\alpha \in \mathbb F_p$ there are $p^{d-1}$ monic polynomials of degree $d$ that vanish at $\alpha$.  This would give a maximum of $\lvert \mathbb F_p \rvert \cdot p^{d-1} = p^d$ polynomials with a root in $\mathbb F_p$, which is too weak a bound. However, we counted polynomials with $k$ roots in $\mathbb F_p$ $k$ times and such a polynomial certainly exist for some $k \geq 2$. Therefore the number of monic polynomials with a root in $\mathbb F_p$ is strictly less than $p^d$. In other words, there must be a polynomial of degree $d$ without roots in $\mathbb F_p$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer presents another approach to show that *irreducible* polynomials of any degree exist.  It is purely based on counting arguments that can be derived without (and in fact predate) the theory of splitting fields.

Fix a prime $p$ and let $A_n$ for $n\geq 1$ be the number of irreducible monic polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$.  The following expression for $A_n$ dates back to Gauss and Dedekind:

$$n A_n = \sum_{d \mid n} \operatorname{\mu}\left(\frac n d \right) p^d$$

where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). Since $\mu$ takes values in $\{-1,0,1\}$ and $\mu(1)=1$ this shows that $A_n>0$ for all $n\geq 1$. The formula above is the [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) (already known to Dedekind) of $$p^n = \sum_{d \mid n} d A_d.$$ This also suffices to show that $n A_n > 0$ since the summands for $d < n$ are too small to sum to $p^n$ (using the bound $d A_d \leq p^d$).  This second identity in turn follows from counting the number of ways in which irreducible polynomials can be multiplied to give all polynomials of a given degree which leads to the “generating” identity $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x^n)^{A_n} \equiv 1-px \pmod {x^m}$$ for any $m \geq 1$.