# Polynomials with no solution in polynomial ring $( \mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

i'm working on a problem and i need some help.

**Problem:**

Let $p$ be a prime number, show that in the polynomial ring $(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb {Z})[x]$ for every $d \in \mathbb N,d \ge 2$ exists a polynomial $f$ with $\deg(f)=d$ with no root in $ \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z $.

**My Idea:**

I already shown it for $p = 3$ so there is no need to talk about that.

for $p \ge 5$ I know that i have to differ the even and odd $\deg(f)$ and i know that i have to use $ \prod_{i = 1} ^d (x-i)+1  $

I can show it for general $d$ but i do not know, how to show it for odd **AND** even $d$.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Doesn't $\prod_{i = 0} ^{d-1} (x-i)+1$ always work for $d\ge p$?

Comment: For every $d\ge 1$ there is a field $\mathbb F=\mathbb F_{p^d}$ with $p^d$ elements. The characteristic of that field is $p$, and the degree is $d$. The multiplicative group of $\mathbb F$ is finite cyclic, so $\mathbb F$ is generated by one element $a$. The minimal polynomial of $f(x)$ of $a$ over $\mathbb F_p$ has degree $d$ and  is irreducible over the prime field. Hence, in particular, $p(x)$  has no roots in $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: @markvs, sure, but the OP does not need $f$ to be irreducible.

Comment: He gets irreducibility as a free bonus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polynomial with no roots over Field $ \mathbb{F}_p $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316827/polynomial-with-no-roots-over-field-mathbbf-p)

Comment: @markvs Thanks a lot for your answer but it does not cover my question about the odd and even deg. Any ideas about that?

Comment: My answer (comment) works for even and odd degrees equally well.

Comment: I am confused. These two of your statements seem to be in conflict: "I can show it for general $d$" vs. "I do not know, how to show it for odd AND even $d$"

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen 
I am told that the answer should differ for odd and even deg. I already show it without odd and even differentiation but I do not know how to include odd and even deg in my proof

Comment: @Tinkerbell_ye I do not see any reason for that. For example, you can always show that there exists  $a$ such that $x^d-x-a$ does the trick, no matter what $d$ is (as long as it is $>1$). Incidentally, $p$ need not even be prime.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4317150/276986) is clearly the most elegant and elementary solution.