# Prove that primes of the form $4k+1$ does divide $m=4q_1q_2\cdots q_n4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I saw similar questions related to this about the primes of the form $4k+3, 4k+1, \cdots$, but still I had some issues to ask.

To prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+3$, where $k$ is nonnegative integers, we can do that with proof by contradiction.

**By Contradiction**:

Let $m = 4q_1q_2\cdots q_n -1$, $m$ is of the form $4k+3$ because it's equivalent to $4k-1$. If we assume that primes $q_1, \cdots, q_n$ are primes of the form $4k+3$, which is equivalent to $4k-1$.

Let $m = 4q_1q_2\cdots q_n -1$, but this number is not of the form $4k+3$ as it's larger than all primes $q_1, \cdots, q_n$ of form $4k+3$. But since $m$ is not prime as it's not one of the primes of form $4k+3$, then we conclude that it's a multiple of primes.

None of the $q_i's$ of the form $4k+3$ divides $m$ as none divides $-1$, so we can conclude that $m$ needs to be the product of prime numbers of the form $4k+1$.

We have a contradiction that $m$ is of two forms $4k+1, 4k+3$.

**Question**: Why we concluded that since none of the $q_i's$ of the form $4k+3$ divides $m$ as none divides $-1$, so we can conclude that $m$ needs to be the product of prime numbers of the form $4k+1$? Why this form and not any other form specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting this answer to make it constructive, as per @BillDubuque.

Let $S$ be a finite set of primes of the form $4k+3$. The following argument shows there is another such prime, not in $S$. It  follows that there must be infinitely many such primes.

The product of two numbers of the form $4k+1$ is again of that form (easy to check).

There are only two kinds of odd primes when you work modulo $4$: some of the form $4k+1$, others of the form $4k+3$, since the numbers of the form $4k$ and $4k+2$ are even.

Let $Z$ be the product of all the primes in $S$ and let $m = 4Z+3$. Since when you divide $m$ by $4$ the remainder is $3$,  $m$ cannot be the product only of primes of the form $4k+1$. It must have at least one prime factor  of the form $4k+3$.
Since none of the  primes in $S$ divides $m$ you have found another prime of that form.

This kind of argument does not work to show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+1$. That's true, but you have to work harder to show it.

Comment: Thank you. Amazing answer. Could you please explain why you selected module 4? Is it because the base form is a multiple of $4$? So the only possibilities for the number is to be either of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$ (odd)?

Comment: This argument works because there are only two kinds of (odd) primes modulo $4$. You can modify it to prove that for any $n$ there are infinitely many primes _not_ of the form $nk + 1$. That's enough to prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6k+5$. For $n=8$ it tells you there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k+3$, $8k+5$ or $8k+7$. There are actually infinitely many primes of each kind but you need a better proof to know that.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let's sketch the key ideas of the proof in *constructive* (vs. contradiction) form. This yields a simple intuitive algorithm for generating primes of the form $4n-1$ - just like Euclid's classical algorithm (for motivation please browse the **Algorithm** below in parallel with reading the text below).

All $\,q_i>1\Rightarrow m = 4q_1q_2\cdots q_n -1>1\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/911681/242) $\,m\,$ has at least one prime factor.

$\!\!\bmod 4\!:\ m\equiv -1\Rightarrow\,$ some prime factor $\,q\,$ of $\,m\,$ is $\equiv -1\,$ (else by $\,m\,$ odd all prime factors of $\,m\,$ are $\equiv 1\,$ so their product $m\equiv 1,\,$ contra $\,m\equiv -1)$

$q$ is *new* $\,q\neq q_i$ else $\,q\mid\color{#0a0}{q_i},\ q\mid 4q_1\!\cdot \cdot\, \color{#0a0}{q_i}\!\cdot \cdot\,  q_n-\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\Rightarrow q\mid \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\,$ (i.e. $\,m\,$ is *coprime* to all $\,q_k)$.  Hence given any finite list of primes $\equiv -1\pmod{\!4}\,$ we can construct a new one, so the number of such primes is not finite,  i.e. there are  infinitely many.

**Remark** $ $ The [key idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217974/242) is that the sequence $\ m_1 = 3,\,\ \color{#94f}{m_{n}} = \,\color{#c00}{\bf 1} + 4m_1\cdot\cdot\,\color{#0a0}{m_k}\cdot\cdot\, m_{n-1}\,$ is an infinite sequence of *coprimes*, i.e. $\,{\rm gcd}(m_n,m_k) = 1\,$ when $\,n> k,\,$ because it follows that every common divisor of $\,\color{#94f}{m_n},\,\color{#0a0}{m_k}\,$ must further divide $\ \color{#c00}{\bf 1} = \color{#94f}{m_n} - 4m_1\cdot\cdot\, \color{#0a0}{m_k}\cdot\cdot\, m_{n-1}.\,$ Further if we choose prime factors $\,q_i\,$ of each $\,m_i\,$ then they too remain pairwise coprime (thus unequal) and, further, as above, we can choose $\,q_i\equiv -1\pmod{\!4}$.

This *constructive* proof is the natural way to proceed (and is [the way Euclid proceeded](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242)). There is no need to rephrase it as a "trivial" contradiction, i.e. assume it false then prove it true (and doing so not only destroys its *algorithmic* content but also leads to much confusion for readers not adept at such, e.g. the common false conclusion that the new number must be prime, which [is true only in](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217974/242) the (contradictory) hypothetical universe of "the naturals with only finitely many primes").

**Algorithm** $ $ The above constructive proof yields a simple algorithm to generate such primes, viz. subtract $1$ from the product of the prior list of primes, then choose a prime factor $\equiv -1\pmod{\!4}$.

Starting with the empty list of primes with product $= \color{#c00}{\bf 1},$ we construct the new prime

$ 4(\ \ \,)\, -\,\ 1\, = 4(\color{#c00}{\bf 1})\ -\ 1 =\ \ \ \, 3\,  =:\, q_1.\ $ Repeating with the singleton list $\, q_1\,$ leads to

$4(q_1)\, -\, 1 = 4(3)\ \, -\, \ 1 =\,\ 11 \,=:\, q_2.\ $  Repeating with the list $\, q_1,q_2\,$ leads to

$4(q_1q_2 \!)\!-\!1 = 4(3\!\cdot\! 11\!)\!-\!1 =  131 \,=:\, q_3.\ $

They remain prime $\ 3, 11, 131, 17291, 298995971 \ $ till we reach the sixth element

$$ m = 89398590973228811 = 8779\cdot 10079\cdot 1010341471\qquad\qquad$$

where we need to choose a (guaranteed) factor $\,\not \equiv 1\pmod{\!4},\,$ e.g. the least $= 8779$.

You can find further terms in [OEIS sequence A057205](https://oeis.org/A057205)

Using $\,4n\!+\!3\,$ vs. $4n-1$ yields $\, 7,31,13,11287,67,\ldots$ (choosing *least* prime factors)

**Generalization** $ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2966127/242) for a more general result which includes both this result and also Euclid's classical proof as special cases.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying my best to understand concepts. I am not yet expert of math, so thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @Avra I appended a dedcription of the algorithm implied by the proof for generating $4n+3$ primes. If you study that then the idea behind the proof should be much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by saying "assume that there are only finitely many primes of the form $4k+3$.  Call them $q_1,q_2,\ldots q_n$" so we know what we are talking about.  Your second "Let $m=\dots$" is not correct.  $m$ is of the form $4k+3$ by construction.  Because it is greater than all the primes in your list, it cannot be prime.  We conclude that none of the primes of the form $4k+3$ divide $m$ because $m$ is one less than a multiple of them.  $2$ also does not divide $m$ because $m$ is odd.  All the other primes are of the form $4k+1$.