# infinitely many ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

does the ring

$\Bbb Z_2[x]$ have infinitely many ideals like $\Bbb Z[x]$?

How do you know if a ring has a finite number of ideal. particularly asking about seemingly large rings.

Comment: Euclid's theorem on infinitely many primes [generalizes as follows:](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/242) $\tag*{}$ **Theorem** $\ $ An infinite ring $\rm R$ has infinitely many prime ideals
if it has fewer units than it has elements. $\tag*{}$

Answer (score 11):

This case is easy:

$$\{(x),(x^2),\ldots,(x^n),\ldots\}$$

The ideals of this set are all different because $x^j\notin (x^k)$ when $k>j$.

Comment: Works the same for $ R[X] $ for any (unital) ring $ R $.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does have infinitely many, basically if $f$ and $g$ have different degrees then $(f)$ is different from $(g)$.  So at least one for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 4):

It even has an infinite number of *prime* ideals (for each degree $n$ there is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$).

Answer (score 1):

the homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_2$ extends to a homomorphism $\phi':\Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Z_2[x]$ by setting $\phi'(x)=x$. the kernel of this map is the ideal $2\Bbb Z[x]$ which is prime, so $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ is an integral domain. moreover since $\phi$ is surjective it maps ideals in the domain to ideals in its image so any ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$ which is not contained in $2\Bbb Z[x]$ will map to a non-zero ideal in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$. in informal language, although $\phi$ certainly reduces the diversity of ideals, there are still plenty left.